# how we can fetch the domain value from cookie. I'm using the below code. I'm getting the value when i'm using .value.

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

Are we only able to set the Domain value ?
-- It's not returning blank ----

```
Request.Cookies["__RequestVerificationToken_L0FwcGx50"].Domain
```

--It is returning value ---

```
Request.Cookies["__RequestVerificationToken_L0FwcGx50"].Value
```

Comment: You mean you want to get this information from a cookie the client has sent back to the server? That is not possible.

Comment: ok. So it means that we can only set Domain value correct ?

Comment: Yes. Domain, path and expiry are parameters used when _setting_ the cookie, so that the client can base its decision when to send them back (for which request paths, and for how long) on those. Since they are not relevant for anything else, they are not send back to the server, only the cookie name and value are.

Comment: Ok. Thanks you for the clarification.